# Why am I getting java.lang.OutOfMemoryError?

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm trying to allocate 3 X 20485700 Bytes (total: ~600MB).
If I'm writing a program in C++, I can run it without errors,
But the same program (written in java) - I'm getting:
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: java heap space.

I'm using the Eclipse (Juno) - so I think that eclipse is not the problem.
(Xms700m Xmx1024m)

What can I do and what is the problem?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Increase heap size in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565388/increase-heap-size-in-java)

Comment: Are those memory parameters those used to run Eclipse itself, or those specified in your program's run configuration ?

Comment: Specifically see http://stackoverflow.com/a/15517960/1341535 on run configurations.

Comment: Do you set the memory options in your launch config?

Answer (score 2):

Put your VM configuration parameter -Xms700m -Xmx1024m in Run Configuration of your program.

Right click on your program file (the one that contains main()), select "Run As", select "Run Configurations". On this wizard, select tab "JRE". There is a textarea as "VM Arguments". Put your VM parameters in this textarea.

Comment: I did it:
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms700m
-Xmx1024m
   And it didnt work

Comment: @user3668129 This is the configuration for Eclipse, not for the program that you run inside Eclipse.

Comment: How to set the configuration of the program ?

Comment: Right click on your program file (the one that contains main()), select "Run As", select "Run Configurations". On this wizard, select tab "JRE". There is a textarea as "VM Arguments". Put your VM parameters in this textarea.

Answer (score 1):

C++  do not restrict on memory space on allocation Where as Java heap are restricted on memory it take -Xmx and -Xms as parameter and allocate the 
java heap for application usage. If the allocated memory space are occupied and if no more space are available for allocation then GC kicks to clear the dead objects even though after GC if java heap does not have enough space  for object allocation then JVM throws OutOfMemory error to inform user/application developer then the current Xmx is not sufficient for object allocation so it help the developer to increase the Xmx based on the current usage and Application need.

Answer (score 0):

Java applications are allowed to use a limited amount of memory. This limit is specified during application start up. Java memory is separated into two different regions: Heap space and permgen.

> The size of those regions is set during the Java Virtual Machine (JVM) launch by specifying parameters such as -Xmx and -XX:MaxPermSize. If you do not explicitly set the sizes, platform-specific defaults will be used.

Comment: I did it:
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms700m
-Xmx1024m
   And it didnt work

Comment: try changing it to -Xmx2048m